# OpenGL VBO not updating using glBufferSubData

Tags: opengl, dynamic, binding, buffer

I`m trying to update a VBO which is also referenced by a VAO.

The first time I write to the VBO the data seems to be accepted and renders correctly.
*(This is an abstract example how my VBO is inited)*

```
GeometryBuilder.BeginSetup(allocatedIndices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw, 4);
GeometryBuilder.BeginBuffer(allocatedData, BufferUsageHint.StreamDraw);
GeometryBuilder.BindBufferToAttribute(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 48, 0);
GeometryBuilder.BindBufferToAttribute(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 48, 12);
GeometryBuilder.BindBufferToAttribute(2, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 48, 20);
GeometryBuilder.BindBufferToAttribute(3, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 48, 36);
GeometryBuilder.EndBuffer();
geometry = GLEXGeometryBuilder.EndSetup();
```

In the GeometryBuilder.BeginBuffer method the data was allocated using BufferData and after that written using BufferSubData.

As I said. It renders the data from "**allocatedData**" correctly. 
But this is a dynamic mesh so I want to update the VBO using this:

```
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, ID);
// Uncommenting this will make my mesh flicker
//GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(length * sizeof(float)), IntPtr.Zero, BufferUsageHint.DynamicDraw);
GL.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)offset, (IntPtr)(length * sizeof(float)), data);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
```

But this doesnt even remove the original data from "**allocatedData**". It still renders it like nothing happened.(Except if I remove the comment from GL.BufferData, then it renders the initial "**allocatedData**" one frame, but on the next frame it is gone, and so on...)
The rendering code is just binding the VAO and calling DrawArrays. It works for all other meshes too.
I havent found any solution in the internet.

Could It be a driver bug? (Got an Intel HD Graphics on this PC)
Or do I miss something else...

---

## Edit

I solved the problem. 
It was caused by uploading too few vertices to actually override the current mesh.

\o_o/

Comment: Make sure that your `glBufferSubData` does not just error out, i.e. by specifying `offset + size` being greater than the original buffer size.

Comment: I checked it, there is no error...

Comment: @derhass Seems to work only if I update the buffer using "GL.BufferData" with the new data (not with a null pointer). But "GL.BufferSubData" has no effect... why?